# How to name this position in English?

Tags: phrase-request

A teacher in school is supposed to ask students (once a month or a bit more often) about what kind of food they would want to have for lunch daily during the upcoming month, and then, based on their answers, to choose an appropriate food-providing company, call them and sign a contract with them for one month. He/she is also responsible to provide the school's correct address and arrange some students who will be receiving and distributing food when the truck from that company has arrived.

How would that position be properly named in English?

In an Asian country where I live they call this position as "secretary for lunch", which I don't think conveys the correct meaning.

Comment: Arrangements in Britain are very different. School meals are organised by non-teaching staff in accordance with government guidelines (to ensure a healthy diet) and without consulting the students. You could perhaps say _catering secretary_?

Comment: @KateBunting If my grandchildren's schools consulted the pupils, they would just need to order chicken nuggets and fries in bulk, and all the kids would start to look pasty and obese. Except for my granddaughter, who'd want a vegan option. Like her grandpa.

Comment: [is responsible *for inquiring*]

Comment: One inquires **of** a people or a person. In the UK, you can 'enquire' if you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with this role, but based on the description, it sounds like **lunch coordinator** or **lunch supervisor** would be possible names.